# Migrating a vb6 project to a vb.net project (MSFlexGrid to datagridview included)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6

We've been asked to migrate a vb6 project to a vb.net project (.net 3.5 to be more precise).

In this project, we're using the msflexgrid in a bunch of forms, and as far as we know, we have to remake if not all of them, at least 80% of methods and properties in order to make it work.

Is there an easier way to acomplish this? Or we have to sit down and code those methods and properties?

Answer (score 1):

You could add the MSFlexgrid control to a .NET project and use all the same properties and methods. It depends on whether you need something *quickly* or *properly*.

See these other questions and answers for more info:

[Uprading VB6 MSFlexGrid to VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787946/uprading-vb6-msflexgrid-to-vb-net)

[VB6 - VS 2005 VB.net - Flexgrid](http://forums.asp.net/t/1169474.aspx)

[Best equivalent of MSFlexGrid for VB.NET 2005](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?525933-2005-Best-equivalent-of-MSFlexGrid-for-VB-NET-2005)

Comment: Well then you will have to do this the proper way by rewriting the code.